# Manual Mouning from sda1?

Tags: mount, usb-on-the-go

Whenever I plugged in my mouse using the OTG cable the cursor appears.
But whenever my usb drive is plugged in the phone it didn't mount.
What I've tried:
Paragon - Nothing found
Stick Mount - Detects USB plugged in and prompt to mount but nothing happened
busybox mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/otg - Nothing in the mounted folder
Lots of Google Searches.
More Info:
Busybox 1.23.1-Stericson Installed
Rooted(of course)
External Powering don't help
OTG cable works on Galaxy S5(another phone)
Current phone info:
Labelled Model - Amazing X2
Kernel Version - 3.4.0 zte-kernel@Zdroid-SMT
Running on Kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: Does the LED activate when you plug it in (does it react to being plugged)?

Comment: Nope, but sda and sda1 is created in /dev/block so I assumed that it reacts to the plugging.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in other, smaller drives?

Comment: Yes, a thumb drive(2GB) don't gets detected still(tried ntfs, fat32 and fat format)